# is there any way to Uint8ClampedArray imageData render using three.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, three.js, html5-canvas

[program-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQV3C.png)

I'm doing made windows RDP(Remote Desktop Protocol) Web Browser.

I want to stream ImageData(Uint8ClampedArray) to browser with live (every 100ms), and
i success it with using server-side render(node-canvas).

but current my source code is very low-performance. because CPU render can't handle it. (it too much many.) so i want to try GPU parallel computing using WebGL in client. (is it possible?)

i made first time like this, (i'll skip description the authentication procedure)

### Serverside

- step 1: hook the rdp imageData's (to compressed RLE algorithm)
- step 2: decompress imagedata(it compressed RLE algorithm)(make Uint8ClampedArray)
- step 3: canvas putImageData
- step 4: get the dataUrl and cut 'data:image/png;base64'
- step 5: make the buffer base64, so it's same image file buffer, save to express.
- step 5: expree will be make image url (like a https://localhost/10-1.png#timestamp)
- step 5: send imageurl to client using socket.io

### Client-side

- step 1: when the site load up, create 64x64 image tag's in div (like a google map)
- step 2: receive the image url and get Image coordinate using parse image name('10-1.png'->x:640,y:64)
- step 3: change image tag src to received image url.

it current performance is bad (actually not so bad when the resolution size is small).

### Question

- Is there any way Uint8ClampedArray imagedata to texture using three.js?
- is it possible RLE algorithm compressed data extract using GPU in three.js?

Answer (score 1):

I don't belive there is a way to directly draw imagedata using three.js.

But as I see it you have other options:

First of all I don't get way you are not just sending jpg or png data via websockets. Then you could actually use the png and draw it as a sprite with in three.js.

That said, I dont think that the bottleneck is the actual drawing of the data to the canvas and even if it were, webgl wont help you with that. I just tried it using webgl vs just using putImageData(). For a HD Image (1920x1080) it took on average of 14ms with putImageData() and 70ms with WebGL out of 1000 drawings. Now when you need to loop through the pixels because you want to do something in terms of image processing like edge detection than it is a whole different story. There webgl will be on top for sure. And here is why: WebGl is using the GPU that means when you want to do something with the image you first have to load all the data to the gpu which is rather slow. But processing the data is quite fast. Much faster then looping through the pixels of the image in javascript.

So in conclusion I would say your best bet is to send png images via websockets using arraybuffers. On client side draw it to a canvas element.

Here is a link to the webgl stuff that explains how you could use it for image processing: [WebGl Fundamentals: Image Processing](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-image-processing.html)

Comment: hmmm.. thanks! anyway now i'm looking for the OpenCL!